# How could voluntary_ctxt_switches of a thread decreased?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, devops

I tried to get context switches of a thread with below script:

```
text=`cat /proc/$pid/task/$tid/sched | grep voluntary_switches`
ts=`date +%s%3N`
vol=`echo "$text" | grep nr_vol | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{$1=$1};1'`
non_vol=`echo "$text" | grep nr_invol | cut -d':' -f2 | awk '{$1=$1};1'`

echo "$tid,$ts,$vol,$non_vol"
```

I can get an output consists of 4 columns which are

1. thread id
2. timestamp in millisecond
3. voluntary_ctxt_switches
4. nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches

I run the script 5 times, and got results from 2nd,3rd,4th round:

```
<tid>,1531390066833,10,0
<tid>,1531390082618,10,0
<tid>,1531390098127,7,0
```

As you can see, timestamp kept increasing but the voluntary_ctxt_switches decreased.

I can't understand how could this happen since voluntary_ctxt_switches is an accumulative counter.